# F# version of haskell pattern match

Tags: haskell, syntax, f#, pattern-matching

How do I do this haskell in F# cleanly?

```
add 1 2 x = 3 + x
add 1 x y = 1 + x + y
add z x y = z + x + y
```

Comment: I do not know haskell, what is the goal here? This looks like an optimization that the compiler would catch and solve. I think trying to to write an equivalent in F# with pattern matching would be slower. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: gjvdkamp, its not an optimization, its a syntactic device that makes each case easier to read. `f 1 = x; f 2 = y` is translated to `f a = case a of 1 -> x ; 2 -> y` - http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.4.3.1

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't overload the function itself, but you can use pattern matching directly:

```ml
let add z x y =               // curried multiple parameters
    match z, x, y with        // convert to three-tuple to match on
    | 1, 2, x -> 3 + x
    | 1, x, y -> 1 + x + y
    | z, x, y -> z + x + y
```

Usage is as expected: `add 1 2 3`

If you're willing to use tuples as arguments (ie forgo currying and partial application), you can even write it more shorthand:

```ml
let add =                     // expect three-tuple as first (and only) parameter
    function                  // use that one value directly to match on
    | 1, 2, x -> 3 + x
    | 1, x, y -> 1 + x + y
    | z, x, y -> z + x + y
```

Usage now is: `add (1, 2, 3)`

Comment: Thanks! I was searching for f# pattern matching examples all over and no one was matching more than one parameter in samples, I was given to the impression you couldn't do this.

Comment: @Jimmy : Technically a single tuple is being matched here, so you weren't wrong...

Comment: @ildjarn : only in the second example which isn't what I would use becuase you lose currying/partial application which I feel is one of the most beneficial parts of these languages

Comment: @Jimmy : In `match z, x, y with`, `z, x, y` is a single tuple. The _add function_ doesn't take a single value, but you can only match on a single value.

Comment: @ildjarn : If that's so, currying is always lost when you do multiple parameter matches in f#. Is that accurate? Yamen's post makes it sound like the first option he lists is still curried. Is yamen incorrect on this?

Comment: @Jimmy : No, the `add` function is curried, but it's then taking the curried parameters `z`, `x`, `y` and using them to construct a single tuple, `int * int * int`, and matching on that tuple. The second option takes a single tuple directly so that it can use the `function` shorthand. Point being, you can only match on multiple parameters by fusing them into a single object first.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa I've updated the answer slightly (added comments) to make it clearer for you.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa "currying is always lost when you do multiple parameter matches in f#". Just to confuse you a bit more, all of the variable bindings here are patterns even when written in curried form.

Answer (score 8):

Recall in Haskell that the [general form of functions](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.4.3.1) as a list of declarations with patterns:

```
f pat1 ... = e1
f pat2 ... = e2
f pat3 ... = e3
```

is just sugar for the `case` analysis:

```
f x1 .. xn = case (x1, .. xn) of
                (pat1, ..., patn) -> e1
                (pat2, ..., patn) -> e2
                (pat3, ..., patn) -> e3
```

so the same translation can be made to other languages with pattern matching but without declaration-level patterns.

Comment: I realize it's just a case, but the reason the sugar exists in haskell is for cleanliness, I was hoping something similar existed in f#, and as yamen pointed out, the matching in f# can work in the same fashion

Answer (score 5):

This is purely syntactic. Languages like Haskell, Standard ML and Mathematica allow you to write out different match cases as if they were different functions:

```
factorial 0 = 1
factorial 1 = 1
factorial n = n * factorial(n-1)
```

whereas languages like OCaml and F# require you to have a single function definition and use `match` or equivalent in its body:

```
let factorial = function
  | 0 -> 1
  | 1 -> 1
  | n -> n * factorial(n-1)
```

Note that you don't have to copy the function name over and over again using this syntax and you can factor match cases more easily:

```
let factorial = function
  | 0 | 1 -> 1
  | n -> n * factorial(n-1)
```

As yamen wrote, do currying with `let f a b = match a, b with ...` in F#.

In the classic red-black tree implementation, I find the duplication of the function names and right-hand sides in Standard ML and Haskell quite ugly:

```
balance :: RB a -> a -> RB a -> RB a
balance (T R a x b) y (T R c z d) = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
balance (T R (T R a x b) y c) z d = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
balance (T R a x (T R b y c)) z d = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
balance a x (T R b y (T R c z d)) = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
balance a x (T R (T R b y c) z d) = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
balance a x b = T B a x b
```

compared to the equivalent OCaml or F#:

```
let balance = function
  | B, z, (T(R, y, T(R, x, a, b), c) | T(R, x, a, T(R, y, b, c))), d
  | B, x, a, (T(R, z, T(R, y, b, c), d) | T(R, y, b, T(R, z, c, d))) ->
      T(R, y, T(B, x, a, b), T(B, z, c, d))
  | a, b, c, d -> T(a, b, c, d)
```